# Why when using an overloaded constructor "new" is required?

Tags: scala

When attempting to provide an overloaded constructor as below

```
  case class Neuron(weight: Double, tHold: Double, var isFired: Boolean, inputNeuron: List[Neuron], id: String) {
    def this() = this(0 , 0 , false , List() , "")
  }

  val n1 = Neuron()  

causes compile time error : not enough arguments for method apply: (weight: Double, tHold: Double, isFired: Boolean, inputNeuron:
```

So I need to use :

```
val n1 = new Neuron()
```

But if I remove the overloaded "this" reference I can call the constructor without using "new"  :

```
case class Neuron(weight: Double, tHold: Double, var isFired: Boolean, inputNeuron: List[Neuron], id: String)

val n = Neuron(0.0,0.0,false,List(),"")
```

Why do I need to use the "new" in above scenario and why only when using an overloaded constructor is "new" required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One could argue either way whether additional constructors should be propagated to the companion object's apply method (which is what `Neuron()` is).  In favor: it's easier.  Against: extra overhead, and if all you want is the extra apply method anyway, it's better to just stick it in the companion.

Speaking of which, do you really want another constructor, or will this do?

```
case class Neuron(w: Double, tH: Double, var fired: Boolean, in: List[Neuron], id: String)
object Neuron {
  def apply() = new Neuron(0, 0, false, Nil, "")
}
```

`new`-less access via the companion object is usually the more convenient way of getting a new instance anyway.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't use `new`, it searches for the `apply` method (companion object), that is clearly not the constructor.

If you want to target the constructor, you have to use `new`.

> But if I remove the overloaded "this" reference, I can call the constructor without using "new"

Note that this point you made in the OP is wrong.
Indeed, even **with** the overloaded `this`, you still can make this call:

```
Neuron(0.0,0.0,false,List(),"") //still apply() called
```

It's completely independent.